# Regex replace string but keep rest of line

Tags: regex

I have the following regex I'm matching against:

```
<dataHolder (.)* outId="(finishTime|startTime)" value="java.lang.String"
```

I want to change the value of value to "java.util.Date" but maintain the rest of the line.

ie

```
<dataHolder inputId="startTime" name="#FF54A7" type="basicType" outId="finishTime" value="java.lang.String" id="kycPreviousTaskEndTime"/>
```

Should render

```
<dataHolder inputId="startTime" name="#FF54A7" type="basicType" outId="finishTime" value="java.util.Date" id="kycPreviousTaskEndTime"/>
```

What replace string should I use to achieve this? I think it involves using $'s?

Comment: make use of [capturing groups and back referencing](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html).

Comment: My issue was the use of (.)* instead of (.*)

Comment: And it would be even better if you added a question mark after the asterisk to make it lazy (non-greedy). The best, however, is not to rely on regular expressions for parsing XML. Use the DOM API instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it in Python:

```
import re

txt = r'<dataHolder inputId="startTime" name="#FF54A7" type="basicType" outId="finishTime" value="java.lang.String" id="kycPreviousTaskEndTime"/>'
txt2 = re.sub(r'value=".*?"', r'value="java.util.Date" ', txt)
```

The regex is simpler than you used.

You just need to serach for `value="` and the rest of the text until the closing quotation marks, then replace it with your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

For manipulation of XML, it is more reliable to use the DOM API. For instance, JavaScript exposes this API as follows (but many other languages have similar interfaces):

```js
var xml = '<dataHolder inputId="startTime" name="#FF54A7" type="basicType" outId="finishTime" value="java.lang.String" id="kycPreviousTaskEndTime"/>';

var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
doc.querySelector('dataHolder').setAttribute('value', 'java.util.Date');
var xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc);

console.log(xml);
```